# TypeInitializationException when using swig for C#

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I am using a C++ framework for a c# project and using swig to connect them.

The problem is that `TypeInitializationException` is thrown every time when I try to create a C++ object wrapper.

C# code

```
TRPoint p = new TRPoint();
```

where TRPoint is a C++ struct

```
typedef struct {
    float x, y;
} TRPoint;
```

[image]

details:

[image]

I have a vc project that build the c++ code into DLL file but I don't know how to link it properly.

Comment: Click on View Detail.  Swig gets to be rather a mixed blessing, debugging code you don't understand when you get exceptions you don't understand is no joy.  Go slower.

Comment: It looks like your missing a pinvoke'd dll.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't put the DLL in correct place to it can't be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception says "unable to load DLL" - it sounds like you've [not built the C++ code](https://github.com/swig/swig/wiki/FAQ#shared-libraries) that SWIG generates, or possibly got a path issue if it is built.

Comment: I have built the C++ code to DLL file but we can't load it using DllImport.

Comment: The link to the FAQ should probably be updated to this one: https://github.com/swig/swig/wiki/FAQ#shared-libraries